# Test setTimeout with React Native Testing Library and Jest

Tags: react-native, react-native-testing-library

I have a React Native app with the following `Player` component that infinitely calls a `play()` function with a `setTimeout`. I'm using `react-native-testing-library` for rendering/testing along with `jest`.

I am trying to test this `setTimeout` function. Specifically, I want to spy on the function so that I can expect the `setTimeout` to have been called any number of times after a given set of seconds. For example, after 3 seconds, the function should have been called 3 times. I am having issues testing this however. My current test looks like this:

```
fit('displays the content', async () => {
            //jest.useFakeTimers();
          
            const { debug, toJSON, getByText, getByTestId } = render(
                <Player token={'test-token'} saveToken={saveTokenMock} />
            );
            //jest.runOnlyPendingTimers();
            const data = {"device":{"id":58,"updated_at":"2021-07-05T01:39:53.588Z","events":[{"my data here"}]}]}};
            mock.onPost('https://www.mydomain.io/api/v1/devices/events').reply(200, data);

            await waitFor(() => {
                expect(getByTestId('imageAsset')).toBeTruthy();
                expect(toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot()
                
            });
            
})
```

When I add the `jest.useFakeTimers()` and `jest.runOnlyPendingTimers()`, the `waitFor` function errors with a `timeout` error. How can I spy on the setTimeout? Here is the general idea of my component:

```
class Player extends Component {
   componentDidMount(){
       this.play()
    }

   play() {
     //does some things

     setTimeout(play, 1000)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can advance the time using [advanceTimersByTime](https://jestjs.io/docs/timer-mocks#advance-timers-by-time) provided by jest.
In order to check the number of the function calls, use  [toHaveBeenCalledTimes](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeencalledtimesnumber).

The provided example in Jest documents is very similar to your component.